# How to loop through the provided parameter?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a following code:

```
function test() {
    for ft in "$1"; do
        echo $ft
    done
}

test 5
```

I am trying to loop through number 12, therefore I want ft to be `1,2,3,4,5` respectively in each loop. But it is just printing 5. I also tried `{1..$1}` but result is still same. Please help!

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63931/how-to-iterate-through-a-comma-separated-list-and-execute-a-command-for-each-ent

Comment: Looks more like [How to convert an input parameter to integer value in a for loop in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418809/how-to-convert-an-input-parameter-to-integer-value-in-a-for-loop-in-bash) to me

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver!

Comment: You are only providing one argument to your function. Looping over that would just print `5` (not `12`).  It's unclear what it is you are actually wanting to do.  How is the sequence `1,2,3,4,5` related to `12`?

Comment: @Kusalananda My bad. Actually it's 5 not 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking.  Do you want to supply a parameter, and loop over the values from 1 to that value?  If so, you can do this with bash (and probably other shells as well:

```bsh
function test() {
    for ((i = 1; i <= $1; ++i)); do
        echo $i
    done
}

test 12
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

If you don't have a shell that supports the `for(...)` syntax, you can do the same thing with:

```bsh
function test() {
    i=1

    while [ $i -le $1 ]; do
        echo $i
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Give the function a single integer and let it output the integers between some start value (1) and that integer:

   ```
   count_up () { seq "$1"; }
   ```

   or

   ```
   count_up () {
       for (( i = 1; i <= $1; ++i )); do
           echo "$i"
       done
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   count_up () {
       value=1

       while [ "$value" -le "$1" ]; do
           echo "$value"
       done
   }
   ```

   or any other number of variations.
2. Give the actual integers as arguments to the function using e.g. `count_up {1..5}` and define the function as simply

   ```
   count_up () { printf '%s\n' "$@"; }
   ```

   or

   ```
   count_up () {
       for value do
           echo "$value"
       done
   }
   ```

   Although, there would not be much point in doing it this way as you could just call `seq 5` or use `printf '%s\n' {1..5}` directly (also, the function should probably be called something like `list_args` instead).